# Why can't I get my minecraft mods to work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I've installed Forge 1.12.2 and all of the mods I installed are 1.12.2. I dragged all of the mod .jar files into the ".minecraft>mods>mods" folder and ran the forge profile on the launcher. However, when it loads, it only says that it has 4 mods loaded/active, which are the default ones.

Answer (score 2):

The second `mods` folder isn't supposed to be there. All your mod .jars should be placed like `.minecraft/mods/mod.jar`. Forge Mod Loader only recognizes the mods in that folder, and that folder alone.